# Make 2 segments the size of 1 in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with 3 segments created in the `storyboard`. I want to programmatically add another segment, and make the middle 2 segments the size of 1 segment. Here is an image to illustrate:

In `storyboard`:

[image]

What I want to achieve programmatically:

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
CGFloat segmentWidth = self.segment.frame.size.width;

[self.segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"titleName" atIndex:2 animated:NO];

[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 4 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 4 forSegmentAtIndex:2];

[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:3];
```

It didn't give me the desirable effects. The widths were weird. How can I get the widths to be like the second image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Half of 1/3 is not 1/4. It is 1/6.
2. You will probably want to set *three* of the segments and leave the last one to be set automatically to fill the remainder.
3. Don't run your code too early - if you do, the segmented control may not have achieved its final frame yet, so your `segmentWidth` will be wrong.

Comment: I didn't think of it that way. (I was thinking that there were 4 segments, so I divided it by 4. I know that doesn't make sense.) Thank you!!