# Apply auto-layout to UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uisegmentedcontrol

I set custom widths for segments in `UISegmentedControl`. Because of that, the `SegmentedControl` doesn't use `auto-layout`. (In the storyboard, I applied a `constraint` on all 4 sides of the `SegmentedControl`.)

Here is my code:

```
CGFloat segmentWidth = self.segment.frame.size.width;

[self.segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"titleName" atIndex:2 animated:NO];    
[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 6 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 6 forSegmentAtIndex:2];

[self.segment setWidth:segmentWidth / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Here's an image to illustrate what this code does:

[image]

Is there a way to add `auto-layout` to the `segments`?

Comment: Post your screenshot about your autoLayout, it seems that  you constraint is the problem

Comment: `Auto-layout` is applied to the `SegmentedControl` as a whole, but not to the individual `segments`. So when the `view` containing the `SegmentedControl` widens, the `segments` aren't equally wider, the last `segment` gets wide instead of all the `segments` widening. I know this is a bit confusing. Let me know if you understood

Comment: Probably you cannot set individual segments with auto-layout. This is referenced from [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html): **The UISegmentedControl object automatically resizes segments to fit proportionally within their superview unless they have a specific width set.** Similar to the `textLabel` for the `UITableViewCell`, Apple handle some of the GUI for consistency. If you want more control over it, you can always make your custom SegmentControl with for example buttons.

Comment: What do you want to acheive then can u post the image for that too

Comment: It seems we've seen this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179886/make-2-segments-the-size-of-1-in-uisegmentedcontrol Look carefully at my answer. Your setting of the segment size must _respond_ to autolayout's changes in the width of the segmented control; it must not _precede_ it.

Comment: @matt Your'e right. We did discuss something similar. I wasn't sure whether I should create a new question or not. I create a new question because I didn't think this was completely related to the other question. It is a new topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code is in the wrong place. Put it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and all will be well.

Comment: I placed it in a `buttons` action. So it gets called after that.

Comment: But if auto layout operates and the size of the segmented control changes, your code won't run again that way. You need it to run _automatically_ - every time auto layout performs layout. That is why it needs to go in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: You asked "Is there a way to add auto-layout to the segments". I'm telling you how. If your code is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, then the segments will adjust to whatever the segmented control does and the proportions will always be right.

Comment: Can I all `viewDIdLayoutSubviews` from the `buttons` action?

Comment: Mmmmmm, you probably shouldn't. But you could have both the button and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call some single method. - Or just duplicate the code (not great practice, I know).

Comment: I'm gonna have to toggle between the images posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179886/make-2-segments-the-size-of-1-in-uisegmentedcontrol. Is there any way I can do that with having the `segments` fit proportionally within their superview?

Comment: Should the last comment be a new question, or should I edit the existing one?

Comment: Toggling between those images (three vs. four segments) has nothing to do with auto layout. You already know how to add or remove segments.

Comment: But I when I go from 3 to 4 segments, (and vice versa), I want  the segments width to fit proportionally within their superview. Meaning when the view containing the `SegmentedControl` width changes. I don't want just 1 segments width to change, I want all the segments to change equally.

Comment: "when the view containing the SegmentedControl width changes" When that happens, you will hear about it because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called. That is what my answer tells you. In your implementation, set up your segments however you desire.

Comment: Oh!! I guess that was where I was confused. I thought it only gets called once, the first time the views get laid out. Thanks